# Control + C (^C) didn't work or break the loop - Mac Darwin

Tags: macos, loops, signals, exit, kill

I'm on Mac 10.12.6 (using gnu-sed aka gsed as sed was crying on Mac for `-i` option)

So I created the following code to make a test change in a file (to test svn hookup and triggering of a Jenkins job). Everything works! but while the following code snippet is running at `$` prompt on my Mac machine, `it's not exiting out` if I press **control+C** (^C).

The code is simple, it just takes a backup of a SVN versioned file somewhere, performs one sed operation, checks in the file (SVN) and then replaces the file back with it's original copy. The loop runs 100 times.

```
for i in {001..100}; do echo $i; cp index.html ~/AKS/utu-index.html; ls -l index.html; echo; gsed -i "s/lineNvalueM/lineNvalue${i}/" index.html; svn ci -m "ignore comment line lineNValueM $i change " /Users/Arun/AKS/svn_06/us-trunk-us/us; echo; sed -n '2p' index.html; echo; cp ~/AKS/utu-index.html index.html; svn ci -m "revert last change" /Users/Arun/AKS/svn_06/us-trunk-us/us; echo; ls -l index.html; sed -n '2p' index.html; echo; done
```

Pressing permanent / random multiple `^C` to come out to the $ prompt didn't work, why?

I'm getting the following output (**^C** below didn't break it):

```
001
-rw-r--r--  1 Arun  staff  5749 Oct 26 09:17 index.html

^Csvn: E200015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200015: Caught signal

<!-- TEST CHANGE PLEASE IGNORE lineNvalue001 -->

^Csvn: E200015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200015: Caught signal

-rw-r--r--  1 Arun  staff  5749 Oct 26 09:25 index.html
<!-- TEST CHANGE PLEASE IGNORE lineNvalueM -->

002
-rw-r--r--  1 Arun  staff  5749 Oct 26 09:25 index.html

^Csvn: E200015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200015: Caught signal

<!-- TEST CHANGE PLEASE IGNORE lineNvalue002 -->
```

Comment: Duplicate?: https://serverfault.com/questions/105386/bash-loop-how-to-stop-the-loop-when-i-press-control-c-inside-a-command

Comment: Trap makes sense. But putting `... || break` didn't help in all cases. FYI. One time it worked, in another, it didn't. ^C was ignored again. Tried `.... || break 2` as well. The case where it didn't work is, try pressing `^C` as soon as `Checked out revision NNNNN.` line is displayed by SVN. So there are cases, where it'll fail. I'll see if trap would do it, but Im doubting that (seems like process control is not coming back to parent ??)